# Refresh Countdown Timer in .Net From Client Side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to refresh a countdown timer once a page is already loaded from the client side in ASP.NET/C# and if so, how? Once the timer is already going, I need to be able to refresh the timer from the server side with a new value. Basically, I am trying to replicate beezid.com in ASP.NET.

Edit: I guess what I mean is how do you dynamically refresh the countdown timer in real-time without polling to occur.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JavaScript SetTimeout and handle that to an Ajax call!!!